# Python: How to Substitute Variables in Strings Read from a text File

Tags: python, bash, substitution, evaluate

I am reading a string from a text file into a Python program.
The strings read have variables-names defined in Python code. How can I read the text string from a file and then substitute variables in it with their value?

On Bash I do it using `${variable-name}` in text file.

Comment: it depends how you specifed your variables in the file

Comment: it's not a duplicate actually, totally different question, if you don't know bash don't close the question

Comment: It's not a duplicate question.

Comment: This is a closest question I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413950/replacing-variable-names-in-string-with-values-from-list-and-avoiding-redundant